# Trouble styling sorted xslt template

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to style some xml:

```
<campers>
  <camper>
    <firstname>James</firstname>
    <lastname>West</lastname>
    <gender>Boy</gender>
  </camper>
  <camper>
    <firstname>Adam</firstname>
    <lastname>West</lastname>
    <gender>Boy</gender>
  </camper>
  <camper>
    <firstname>Ann</firstname>
    <lastname>Landers</lastname>
    <gender>Girl</gender>
  </camper>
  <camper>
    <firstname>Billy</firstname>
    <lastname>Batson</lastname>
    <gender>Boy</gender>
  </camper>
  <camper>
    <firstname>Diana</firstname>
    <lastname>Prince</lastname>
    <gender>Girl</gender>
  </camper>
</campers>
```

I want to have them sorted by gender then name, but I also want to have a header by gender. I cannot seem to get this to work. My output should look like this:

### Campers

#### Boys

Batson, Billy
West, Adam
West, James

#### Girls

Landers, Ann
Prince, Diana

Using the following xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="1.0"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <head><title>Camper list</title></head>
    <body style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:8pt;">
    <h2>Campers</h2>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//camper">
      <xsl:sort select="gender" />
      <xsl:sort select="lastname" />
      <xsl:sort select="firstname" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="camper">
  <xsl:if test="not(gender = preceding::gender)">
    <h3><xsl:value-of select="gender"/>s</h3>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="lastname"/><xsl:text>, </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="firstname"/><br />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately, my output looks like this:

### Campers

Batson, Billy
West, Adam

#### Boys

West, James

#### Girls

Landers, Ann
Prince, Diana

I am sure I am doing something wrong with the sort, or the sort is not being used as I expect it to be. Any suggestions would help.

Thanks,

David

Addendum: Based on lwburk's solution, here is what I came up with:

```
<xsl:key name="campers-by-gender" match="camper" use="gender" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head><title>Camper xsl test</title></head>
        <body style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:8pt;">
            <h2>Campers</h2>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="campers">
    <xsl:for-each select="camper[count(. | key('campers-by-gender', gender)[1]) = 1]">
        <h3><xsl:value-of select="key('campers-by-gender', gender)/gender"/>s</h3>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('campers-by-gender', gender)">
            <xsl:sort select="lastname" />
            <xsl:sort select="firstname" />
            <xsl:value-of select="lastname"/><xsl:text>, </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="firstname"/><br />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks for all the help and good ideas!
D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group first and then sort:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="1.0"/>
    <xsl:key name="gender" match="camper" use="gender" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
        <head><title>Camper list</title></head>
        <body style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:8pt;">
        <h2>Campers</h2>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template
        match="camper[generate-id()=generate-id(key('gender', gender)[1])]">
        <h3><xsl:value-of select="gender" />s</h3>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('gender', gender)" mode="out">
            <xsl:sort select="lastname" />
            <xsl:sort select="firstname" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="camper" mode="out">
        <xsl:value-of select="lastname" />
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="firstname" />
        <br />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="camper" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which produces the following output on your source document:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Camper list</title>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 8pt;">
<h2>Campers</h2>
<h3>Boys</h3>
Batson, Billy<br />
West, Adam<br />
West, James<br />

<h3>Girls</h3>
Landers, Ann<br />
Prince, Diana<br />
```

Comment: @lwburk: This is the second answer I see you don't use the `key()` for process the whole group. That's confusing people.

Comment: @Alejandro - Can you explain further? I'm afraid you know something I don't.

Comment: @lwburk: Use `<xsl:apply-templates select="key('gender', gender)" mode="out">` instead of `<xsl:apply-templates select="../camper[gender=current()/gender]" mode="out">`

Comment: @Alejandro - Thank you. I am very new to XSLT and don't always think of the most obvious or idiomatic solutions. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: @lwburk: Thanks for the help! This set me on the right path. See the Addendum to the question for my solution.

Comment: @djpMusic - You're welcome. I prefer templates over `for-each`, but lots of people do it your way, which is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

im sure there are several more simple ways to do this!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

        <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="1.0"/>

        <xsl:template match="/">
                <html>
                        <head>
                                <title>Camper list</title>
                        </head>
                        <body style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:8pt;">
                                <h2>Campers</h2>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="//camper[gender='Boy']">  
                                        <xsl:sort select="lastname" />
                                        <xsl:sort select="firstname" />
                                </xsl:apply-templates>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="//camper[gender='Girl']">
                                        <xsl:sort select="lastname" />
                                        <xsl:sort select="firstname" />
                                </xsl:apply-templates>
                        </body>
                </html>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="camper">
                <xsl:if test="position() &lt; 2">
                        <h3>
                                <xsl:value-of select="gender"/>s
                        </h3>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="lastname"/>
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="firstname"/>
                <br />
        </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```